# How to pass a method with multiple parameters as argument of another method

Tags: .net, vb.net, func

I have multiple and different methods that I can't edit:

```
    Public Function Test1(A As Integer, B As String, C As Boolean) As Boolean
    Public Function Test2(A As Boolean, B As Double) As DataTable
    Public Function Test3(A As String) As Integer
```

I started creating a class like this:

```
Public Class MyWrapperClass

    Dim _method As Action()

    Public Sub New(Method As Action())
        _method = Method
    End Sub

    Public ExecuteFunction()
        _method()
        ' And do something with the result
    End Function

End Class
```

---

The problem is:

How can I pass a `Method` that has some arguments and recall them in `ExecuteFunction`? I tried using `Action` but it does not fit with its definition and usage.

---

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
Dim test1 = new MyWrapperClass(Test1)
test1.ExecuteFunction(1, "test1", true)

Dim test2 = new MyWrapperClass(Test2)
test2.ExecuteFunction(true, 0.34)
```

Is it possible? How can I get this effect / which pattern should I use?

Comment: `Action` wont work: `[Action] Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value.`.   Delegates would work except it looks like you are trying to ignore that the params and returns are all different.

Comment: You should be able to do this with reflection but you are totally throwing out all compile time checking which can help prevent errors before they get to the user. This is a bad idea. IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`How can I pass a Method that has some arguments`

The problem is the code which creates and uses `MyClassWrapper` isnt passing in any arguments, and since `Action` has no return, it is not the right choice if you need the return.

The example shows creating a new object wrapper for each method, which seems inefficient.  For simplicity, I changed the arguments  to basic types for the class you dont have access to:

```
Public Function Test1(A As Integer, B As String, C As Boolean) As Int32
Public Function Test2(A As Boolean, B As Double) As String
Public Function Test3(A As String) As Integer
```

The different names *seems* to indicate the target methods are *not* overloads, but `MyWrapperClass` seems to wants to interact with them as if they are by using the same name `ExecuteFunction`.  Even though the question code is contrived for posting here, the `CantEditClass` is exposing 3 different methods.  I am not sure it adds clarity to have to discern which method is being called by the order/type of arguments.

#### Basic Answer

Literally pass the address of the function to the Wrapper method. For this, the wrapper methods could be declared using `Func()` to define the method chained to:

```
Public Function Test1Exec(f As Func(Of Int32, String, Boolean, Int32), a As Int32) As Int32
    Dim n As Int32 = f(a, "foo", False)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private wrapper As Wrapper
Private objSealed As CantEditClass
...
wrapper = New Wrapper
objSealed = New CantEditClass   
...
Dim b = wrapper.Test1Exec(AddressOf objSealed.Test1, 6)
```

### Declare a Delegate for Reuse

```
' declared with the other objects
Private fDel As Func(Of Int32, String, Boolean, Int32) 
...
' initialized:
fDel = AddressOf objSealed.Test1
...
Dim b = wrapper.Test1Exec(fDel, 6)
```

The `fDel` delegate can be set once if declared at some class/form level.  If `objSealed` is recreated, the code will need to reset the delegate.  Especially with a generic name or quasi overload the named Delegate can help you keep track of which is which.

Both are rather cumbersome because the burden is put on the consuming code.

#### Delegate as a Wrapper Type

You could also have the wrapper "hold onto" the delegate.  In `Wrapper`:

```
Public Delegate Function Test1Delegate(a As Int32, b As String, c As Boolean) As Int32
Public Function Test1aExec(f As Test1Delegate, a As Int32) As Int32
    Dim n As Int32 = f(a, "foo", False)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim fDel2 As Wrapper.Test1Delegate = AddressOf objSealed.Test1
...
b = wrapper.Test1aExec(fDel2, 6)
```

Slightly less cumbersome.  You could also let the wrapper set all these up and hold onto them by passing the sealed class object in the constructor:

```
Private Delegate Function Test2Delegate(a As Boolean, b As Double) As String
Private Test2D As Test2Delegate

Private Delegate Function Test3Delegate(a As String) As Integer
Private Test3D As Test3Delegate

Public Sub New(target As CantEditClass)
    ' internal assignment
    Test2D = AddressOf target.Test2
    Test3D = AddressOf target.Test3
End Sub
```

#### Smart Wrapper, No Delegates

Delegates may make sense if there is variation in which of these is invoked in conjunction with a `Wrapper` method.  If not, the `Wrapper` could be a little smarter:

```
Public ReadOnly TargetObject As CantEditClass
' alternatively pass the object 
' if the calling code needs it for something like events
Public Sub New()
    ' internal mapping
    Dim TargetObject = New CantEditClass
End Sub

Public Function Text1Ex(arg1 As Int32, arg2 As String, arg3 As Boolean) As Int32
    Dim result = TargetObject.Test1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    ' work with result
    Return If(arg3, arg1, -arg1)
End Function
```

The code can invoke either version easily:

```
MyWrap = New Wrapper()

' call EXtended wrapper version
Dim result = MyWrap.Text1Ex(42, "ziggy", False)
' invoke the native version:
result = MyWrap.TargetObject.Test1(42, "zalgo", True)
```