# How Do I Pass A Subprocedure As An Argument VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parameters

I am writing a function that takes an externally defined Sub Procedure and runs it a certain number of times based on variables in the contained class. How do you pass Sub devs as parameters in VB.NET? Or what is an alternative way of doing it? (UPDATE: This is for a timer class for a WPF Application that I will use in my Pong game I'm making. The new method should take a sub procedure as a parameter, and then it tells another sub called `Run()` to execute that sub procedure every x milliseconds)

Comment: A loop is typically used to process something multiple times but you're not really giving us much to go on here.

Comment: Are you looking for [Action Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx).  There is a also `Func` delegate for cases where the method returns something [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33571567/1070452)

Comment: I know that i need use a loop here, but I need to pass in a user defined sub procedure. So a call to this function would be loopCommandBasedOnUnAccessibleData(printHelloWorld()) and it would print "Hello World" a variable # of times

Comment: Too often, people ask the wrong question. Why don't you tell us (completely) what you are trying to do so we can give you the right answer. As it is now, it's a crap-shoot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare your method (`Sub`) as taking an [`Action Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter.  This allows you to pass the address of a void method (`HelloWorld`)  as a parameter:

```
Private Sub DoSomething(a As Action)
    ' pick a random number 1-5
    Dim v = RNG.Next(1, 6)
    ' call whatever v times
    For n As Int32 = 0 To v
        a()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub HelloWorld()
    Console.WriteLine("Null Spark says 'Hello, World!'")
End Sub
```

Calling it would just be:

```
DoSomething(AddressOf HelloWorld)
```

As MSDN notes, `Action` encapsulates a method that has no parameters and *does not return a value*.  To include parameters use `Action(of T)` (see next); to return a value (use a function), use `Func`, [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571567/1070452)

---

When there are params involved use `Action(Of T)`.  You can also declare variables as `Action Delegates` which can make the code easier to read:

```
Private HelloAction As Action(Of Int32)
```

Then somewhere like a form load:

```
HelloAction = AddressOf HelloWorld
...
Private Sub DoSomething(a As Action(Of Int32))
    Dim v = RNG.Next(1, 6)
    For n As Int32 = 0 To v
        a(n)            ' pass the int param
    Next
End Sub
```

In this case, `HelloWorld` would be:

```
Private Sub HelloWorld(x As Integer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) This is honestly a HUGE help for me.